# Why do I get java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "∞"?

Tags: java, exception, runtimeexception

here's the scenario.
I am dynamically generating the components to be displayed on the JPanel according to the data taken from the database.
The user is prompted to enter an integer number and according to that some calculations are done. The output should be given as a decimal value. Therefore, i have assigned the answer to a double and formatted is using DecimalFormat.

I get an error when i pass my double value to the format() method of DecimalFormat eventhough i didn't enter any value as 0.

Here's the error

> java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "∞"    at
>   sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:2043)
>     at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(FloatingDecimal.java:110)   at
>   java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:538)     at
>   java.lang.Double.valueOf(Double.java:502)     at
>   com.boarding.brdrsbllsys.view.Bills.displayOutput(Bills.java:358)     at
>   com.boarding.brdrsbllsys.view.Bills.btnConfirmActionPerformed(Bills.java:186)
>     at com.boarding.brdrsbllsys.view.Bills.access$200(Bills.java:27)    at
>   com.boarding.brdrsbllsys.view.Bills$3.actionPerformed(Bills.java:123)
>     at
>   javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
>     at
>   javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
>     at
>   javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
>     at
>   javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
>     at
>   javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
>     at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6533)    at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)    at
>   java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6298)  at
>   java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)  at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)     at
>   java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)     at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)     at
>   java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
>     at
>   java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4525)
>     at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
>     at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)    at
>   java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)   at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)     at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
>     at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:90)
>     at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)   at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
>     at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)   at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)

The code snippet the error is generated,

```
if (gbc.gridx == 1 && gbc.gridy == i + 1) {
                textConstraints.gridx = 1;
                textConstraints.gridy = i + 1;
                newPanel.add(new JLabel(((JTextField) component).getText()), textConstraints);
                int days = Integer.parseInt(((JTextField) component).getText().trim());
                System.out.println("add num of days");

                DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");

                textConstraints.gridx = 3;
                double a=water / waterdays * days*1.0;
                double boarderWater = Double.valueOf(df.format(a));//error is given in this line
                newPanel.add(new JLabel(boarderWater + ""), textConstraints);
                continue;

            }
```

Please consider that the variables `gbc` and `textConstraints` are GridBagConstraints objects, `water` is a double variable and `waterdays` and `days` are int variables.

What should have been the problem with my code?

Comment: I just seems like the infinity symbol can't be parsed using that method. If you really need to handle that, I'd manually just check for it before trying to parse it.

Comment: *eventhough i didn't enter any value as 0.* -> That looks more like the infinity symbol to me, and not 0.

Comment: The message says: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "∞" at  ... so, what makes you think that this symbol should be parseable as number?

Comment: Does it occur regardless of the values of `water`, `waterdays` and `days`? Could you give an example of these three values which gives this error? [It seems to work with 'normal' values.](https://tio.run/##VZA/i8JAEMX7fIrBNIngniJWwU6uO66wsBCLMbuRjfsn7E6iIn723F4SYW1m4Pce8x5TY4eLml/7XurGOoI6AEbiTmwnSqlRfVunkYqkVOg9/KA0zwSgac9KluAJKazOSg46SNmenDSX4wnQXXz@7wTgNpgF3JCEgy1s2LIYuDQ0Qo4PH4RVxCe0HskwPvoAr4JsxO0TZ7OUpeksL@JgDM4x/CvKm8O0Vu8@k/1s0XHhDlPd3UBZh6oVv1XGK1aNUZjnUbv9w5PQzLbEmvACUiaLDw3WV/Lq@z8)

Comment: Check if the string is `∞` and set it to `Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY` manually

Comment: Why do you format a double as string only to directly parse the string back to a double?

Comment: The stack trace indicates the error occurred in Double.parseDouble, but your code does not call Double.parseDouble.  Are you sure the code in your question is the code which generated that stack trace?

Comment: @VGR The code and stacktrace both contain `Double.valueOf`, which internally does the `Double.parseDouble`.

Comment: Oh, I see Double.valueOf in the stack trace now.  In my browser, it is not on a separate line.  This is why stack traces should be code formatted, not quotation blocked—there should be one stack trace element (“at” item) per line, for readability.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**A simple explanation:**

This error occurs when the **denominator is ZERO** in the division process.

Put the condition(using if else) that your value of denominator should not be equal to zero.

Or if you can't put the condition,

Set up exception handling for the value of denominator is equal to zero, to avoid your application crash.

Use

try{//Your code
}

catch(Exception e){//catch exceptions
}

Answer (score 2):

You haven't provided the values for `water`, `waterdays` and `days`, but based on the error I can only conclude `waterdays` is 0.

Since we are working with doubles here, dividing by 0 won't give an error like with integers, but will instead give a `Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY` as result.

Here an example code-snippet with `waterdays = 0` to reproduce this error:

```
double water = 5.0;
int waterdays = 0;
int days = 3;

DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
double a = water / waterdays * days * 1.0;

double boarderWater = Double.valueOf(df.format(a));
System.out.println(boarderWater);
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##VY5Bi8IwEIXv/RWDvbSHzR8o3lTIYXWhosgiy7RJJd2kKcm0uoi/vaZdlrWnGd68972psce3WnwPgzKtdQR1EBjJG7GVLJVBvbHOIGVRqdF7eEfV3COAtiu0KsETUhi9VQJMOCU5OdVcPs@A7uLT0QkwA4GoYAmNvM7lZBGzOF6kWTRFhA18CRisq2llH7uc7/lh/cW3G77l@1P2aiwsOiHdEUm6/0yPupO7KhEVq35bMP1ryH88ScNsR6wNL5NukldIOuIf0WMYng)

As you can see in the TIO-debug window, the formatter gives the same error `java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "∞"`, because `waterdays` is 0.

Please debug your code to check the value of `waterdays`.